# Async function in loop - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, async-await, axios

I'm working in vue.js. In my code, I try to call 2 methods in loop, but I want the second method to run asynchronously.
The first method call an API to update database. The second method call an API to run workflow, this one make an udpate on file. It is not possible to launch several workflows on the same file.
I want to wait until the result of the second method to continue.

```
class SessionFormationService {
  async UpdateBesoin(
    besoinId: number,
    eventId: number,
    nouveauStatutCode: string,
    prioriteBesoin: string
  ) {
    const url = XXX;
    const result = await axiosApp(url, { ...option, method: "patch" });
    return result.data.sessionFormation as SessionFormation[];
  }
}

export const sessionFormationService = new SessionFormationService();
```

Run workflow:

```
class WorkflowService {
  async updateXml(
    fichierXML: string,
    activityId: number,
    axe: string,
    priority: string,
    bookingId: string,
    bookingVersionNumber: string,
    statutName: string
  ){

    const data = "XXX";
    const xmls ="XXX";
      
    return await axios.post(
      "URL",
      xmls,
      {
        headers: {
          XXX
        }
      }
    )
  }
}
export const workflowService = new WorkflowService();
```

And my app:

```
   validerModification: function() {
     const rows = this.updateRow;
     rows.map(element => {  
         sessionFormationService.UpdateBesoin(
         element.bookingId,
         element.eventId,
         "02",
         element.priorite
       );
         workflowService
         .updateXml(
           element.urlPif,
           element.activityId,
           element.axe,
           element.priorite, 
           element.bookingId,
           "02",
           element.statut
         ); 
     });

     this.updateRow.length = 0;
     rows.length = 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `await` inside a simple loop in an `async` function.

```
// You should probably move this to a service too to keep your component lean and dry.

async function validerModification(rows) {
  for (const element of rows) {
    await sessionFormationService.UpdateBesoin(
      // ...
    );
    await workflowService.updateXml(
      // ...
    );
  }
}
```

Component:

```
validerModification: function() {
   validerModification(this.updateRow).then(function(){
        this.updateRow.length = 0;
  });
}
```